# Flash plugin or additional plugins in Firefox

Tags: firefox, flash

I have been trying to read my online training on Yahoo, but when I click the icon for training, a message box appears saying that I should install additional plugins.
I have tried to install the additional plugins by selecting *Tools* -> *Add-ons* in Firefox, but nothing seems to work.

Why can't I install the Flash plugin in Firefox? And why is Firefox unable to use Adobe Flash Player?

Answer (score 0):

You should install flash-plugin via Ubuntu Software Center via repositories. Te best way to do this is by installing package "ubuntu-restricted-extras" which includes many useful codecs and plugings like flash and java.